# Xcode auto include header for sibiling project

Tags: xcode, static-libraries

i have a workspace in xcode with two project (sibiling, not parent->child) a project is a static library, and other project is a standard app.
Now i need to drag headers file from library project to app project but this a bit annoying, how i need to configure 'header search path' parameter?

thanks

I add other details: now the path is:
    $(SRCROOT)/../Build/Products/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)/include/UtilityLibrary

i create a Build folder and from xcode preferences i configured this folder to receive all builed prioject.